# Declaring classes with base-class gone wrong

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I am new to C#, so sorry if this is a stupid question. I got this idea from PHP / Java. I am building a small mvc-framework. For that we need a Controller. But we have multiple controllers like PlayerController, CarController, BombController.... All of these models extend to the Controller-class.

Example:

```
public abstract class Controller
{

    public string data;

    public Controller(string data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

And:

```
class BlogsController : Controller
{

    public BlogsController(string data) : base(data)
    {
    }

    public void getData()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.data);
    }

}
```

In the Main-class I call the methods this way:

```
Controller blogs = new BlogsController("Test");

blogs.getData();
```

Even with Models (BlogModel extends to Model) I want this structure.

But... I get an error on `blogs.getData();` because 'Controller' has no getData-method.
Thats true, but I want to call the getData-method from the BlogsController (I created with `Controller blogs = new BlogsController("Test");`)

What am I doing wrong? How can I use the custom methods of the BlogsController?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you want to use anything that is specific to `BlogsController`, you need an reference of that type.

Comment: Or add it to the abstract class as an `abstract` method. One way or the other. References to `Controller` will *never* have access to derived methods.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen I know, but I give it the type `Controller` because `BlogsController` 'extends' to `Controller`

Comment: look up how to use `override` key word as well

Comment: But `Controller` doesn't have `getData`. Without downcasting, there is no guarantee that the underlying class has that method! Thus, C# doesn't allow it.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Okay but how is this 'structure' used in C#. Isn't it logic you want a 'base' class like `Controller`

Comment: here's an MSDN article with some basic examples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Here is a more up-to-date version of the MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173149(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Absolutely, you are just using them wrong ;) Hopefully my answer helps. Perhaps we should chat if not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not allowed, as `Controller` does not contain a method called `getData`. Suppose you write the following:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public MyController (string data) : base(data)
    {
    }
}
```

Totally legal. Now lets use it!

```
Controller blogs = new MyController ("Test");

blogs.getData(); //Whoops!
```

`blogs` does not have a method `getData` defined! This behavior isn't specific to C#, it will be the same in any strongly-typed OOP language. This would work:

```
Controller blogs = new BlogsController("Test");

(blogs as BlogsController).getData(); //Better....
```

but will throw if you didn't actually instantiate a `BlogsController` as the cast will fail.

You really have two solutions, hold a derived class reference, so that only the specific derived class can be assigned to it; or, make `getData` part of your "interface":

```
public abstract class Controller
{

    public string data;

    public Controller(string data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public abstract void getData();
}
```

And:

```
class BlogsController : Controller
{

    public BlogsController(string data) : base(data)
    {
    }

    public override void getData()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.data);
    }

}
```

Now every class that derives from `Controller` has to implement `getData` and the call is safe.

Comment: Hey thank you for this clear explanation. How would you suggest to solve this. Is it necessary to derive from `Controller`? How would you build up such mvc-frame?

Comment: `Controller` isn't the question, the real question is what the utility of `getData` is? Is it going to be important to every implementation of `Controller` or just the one? The answer to that question determines the correct solution. If this is still confusing you, perhaps we should chat about OOP design?

Comment: How can we chat? ;) Can I show you my real problem? (the example was an example)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the base class you have does not contain the method called `GetData()`

The method `GetData()` is only available to your `BlogsController` class...

Let me give you a short intro in to how you can achieve `inheritance` and `polymorphism` in C#...

```
void Main()
{
    // Car has inherited two properties from the VehicleBase class, 
    // the Brand propety, and the ProductionDate property
    Car car = new Car { Brand = "Foo", ProductionDate = DateTime.UtcNow };

    // The StartEngine method is declared in the class `Car`, and is available
    // to only its self, as there is no other class inheriting from it.
    car.StartEngine();

    // This is polymorphism... 
    VehicleBase vehicle = car;

    // As the VehicleBase class doesn't inherit from Car, it can not use
    // the StartEngine method... the only way to use it is by casting it 
    // back to a Car.
    Car castedCar = vehicle as Car;
    castedCar.StartEngine();

}

public class VehicleBase
{
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public DateTime ProductionDate { get; set; }
}

public class Car : VehicleBase
{
    public void StartEngine()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Engine started");
    }
}
```

Comment: I will check this out tomorrow. Thanks for your answer;)